# Asp.net Web Service CS file moved?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I hardly use web services, but just noticed now when I created one, the CS file was dumped in the App_Code folder. Is that a new thing?

I always thought it behaved much like an Aspx or Ascx file with the nested code behind CS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using a [Web Site in contrast to Web Application](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx). Web Sites are compiled dynamically at runtime by the ASP.NET runtime. In this model all code goes into the `App_Code` special folder. When deploying you need to upload your source code as well.

On the other hand a Web Application is compiled. You can place the code wherever you like and for things like .ASPX, .ASCX, .ASMX, .ASHX, ... Visual Studio nests the code file next to the markup.